# Bash variable substitution of variable followed by underscore

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable-substitution

The variable `BUILDNUMBER` is set to value 230. I expect `230_` to be printed for the command `echo $BUILDNUMBER_` but the output is empty as shown below.

```
# echo $BUILDNUMBER_

# echo $BUILDNUMBER
230
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The command `echo $BUILDNUMBER_` is going to print the value of variable `$BUILDNUMBER_` which is not set (underscore is a valid character for a variable name as explicitly noted by Jeff Schaller)

You just need to apply braces (curly brackets) around the variable name or use the most rigid `printf` tool:

```
echo "${BUILDNUMBER}_"
printf '%s_\n' "$BUILDNUMBER"
```

PS: Always quote your variables.

Comment: The documentation and the standard use the term "null" for a variable set to an empty string (as opposed to an unset variable). I took the liberty of editing.

Answer (score 17):

As George Vassiliou already [explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358275/22222), that's because you're printing the variable `$BUILDNUMBER_` instead of `$BUILDNUMBER`. The best way to get what you want is to use `${BUILDNUMBER}_` as George explained. Here are some more options:

```
$ echo "$BUILDNUMBER"_
230_
$ echo $BUILDNUMBER"_"
230_
$ printf '%s_\n' "$BUILDNUMBER"
230_
```

Comment: We know what the variable holds, but we don't know what `$IFS` holds, so `echo $BUILDNUMBER"_"` is still wrong. Of the three, only `printf '%s_\n' "$BUILDNUMBER"` is correct if we don't know what `$BUILDNUMBER` or `$IFS` hold.